# Read the bar- QR-code with a scanner on windows 10 system

Tags: python-3.x, usb, barcode-scanner

I have connected a bar- / qr-code scanner to my windows 10 pc via usb.
The scanner is registered on the system.

Now I want to write a python app to read bar- and qr-codes with the scanner.

Yet I am not able to read codes, I get an object as a result.

What I have to do, whta is going wrong???

To access the complete parameter from the scanner is possible.

```
#importing modules
import usb
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1

#device vid / pid
VID = 0x2010 
PID = 0x7638

#access the device registry
backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda X: "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libusb\amd64")

#some tries to get parameters / informations about the device
usb_error = usb.USBError('USB-Error', error_code='error', errno=None)
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VID, idProduct=PID)
dev.set_configuration()
if not dev:
    raise ValueError ("USB device not found")
    exit(1)

config = dev.configurations
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]
ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    custom_match = lambda e: usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN)
ep_adr = ep.bEndpointAddress
dev.backend.open_device
adress = dev.address
manufaktur = dev.manufacturer
conf2 = dev.bNumConfigurations
dev_descriptor = dev.bDescriptorType
ser_num = dev.serial_number
busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
    devices = bus.devices
    for dev in devices:
        print ("Device:", dev.filename)
        print ("  idVendor: %d (0x%04x)" % (dev.idVendor, dev.idVendor))
        print ("  idProduct: %d (0x%04x)" % (dev.idProduct, dev.idProduct))

print('cfg: ', str(cfg))
print('Manufacturer: ', str(manufaktur))
print('Serial Number', str(ser_num))
print('EP: ', ep)

print('Descriptor: ', dev_descriptor)

the actual result:

Device: 
  idVendor: 8208 (0x2010)
  idProduct: 30264 (0x7638)
cfg:    CONFIGURATION 1: 400 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x22 (34 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xc8 (400 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Human Interface Device ====================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x3 Human Interface Device
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :    0x8 (8 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
Manufacturer:  USBKey Chip
Serial Number 202730041341
EP:        ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :    0x8 (8 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
Descriptor:  1
```

Comment: This example code only enumerates USB devices. What's the problem?

Comment: Vendor ID 0x2010 at your source is not registered [USB ID Database](https://www.the-sz.com/products/usbid/) [List of USB ID's](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids), is it a device under development by a new vendor? In general, you can set the scanner to COM port mode, install the device driver, and access it with PySerial etc.

Comment: The problem is to read was the scanner delivered or to open and parse the object, which is delivered from the scanner and is located at the usb interface

Comment: @Christian Mölk, Why do you stick to a special way at the device driver level, such as the implementation of the USB protocol? Using COM port mode and vendor-supplied device driver makes the application program easier and more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

The object you get must be a string with the resulting scan output. Try scanning to a console...

The scanner you have is emulating only a USB keyboard as OUTPUT. 
All the SW inside the scanner produces is a string of bytes as a result of the scanned image.

What you are trying to do is use libusb to talk the the USB hw directly, which will only get you an emulated HID keyboard.

If you want to hack down, you need to jtag the scanner board or scan `config images` to  trigger configuration changes on the device.

Answer (score 0):

my Barcode scanner connected via USB is acting like standard input device (like Keyboard) in Windows 10. When barcode is scanned on opened text file in Notepad, the scanned digits appears in text file, like typing on Keyboard.

Hence for reading into Python39 shell or file in Windows 10, used the python code 'input("scan Barcode: ")' and scanned. I got scanned digits from scanner device.

```
C:\Project\Python39>python
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> input("scan Barcode: ")
scan Barcode: 88H-1010UB-0TV
'88H-1010UB-0TV'
>>>
>>> myBarCodeId = input("Scan barCode please ...")
Scan barCode please ...TARNLK002563
>>>
>>> print(myBarCodeId)
TARNLK002563
>>>
>>> mibar=input("scan me please \n")
scan me please
88H-1010UB-0TV
>>>
>>> print(mibar)
88H-1010UB-0TV
>>>
```